# Changing DPI of Composer Output in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis-2.18

I need to export and print a high quality raster image as a pdf from QGIS 2.18.

No problem exporting the image as a pdf from composer but how can I change the DPI output to maximize quality?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the DPI from `Composition -> Export resolution` setting, as you can see below:

[image]

If the tabs are missing, then right-click the navigation bar and make sure that all the menus are selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, are you sure this answer is for qgis2.18? I haven,t seen these tabs...

Comment: The above tabs are available in all QGIS  versions not only 2.18

Comment: I updated my answer to give more details in case you can't see the tabs.